# spring batch - using flag on assertUpdates to allow reuse of JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: spring, spring-batch

potentially as much as spring question as spring batch.

I want to reuse a JdbcBatchItemWriter where in the default case it will have assertUpdates=true and in my case assertUpdates=false.

What is the method for creating this flag and setting it differently in each job? I've not been able to work it out or find an example.

Thanks

A bit more information - the jobs can be scheduled by quartz or kicked of programatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
void setAssertUpdates(boolean assertUpdates)
```

Public setter for the flag that determines whether an assertion is made that all items cause at least one row to be updated.

for more info see: http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcBatchItemWriter.html